# Was it out of envy that David brought the ark out of the house of Obed-edom in 2 Samuel 6:12?

Tags: david, 2-samuel, ark-of-the-covenant

After having abandoned the Ark for more than three months David quickly removes it from the house of Obed-edom after having heard that God had blessed the house of Obed-edom.

2 Samuel 6:12 NASB

12 Now it was reported to King David, saying, “***The Lord has blessed the house of Obed-edom*** and all that belongs to him, on account of the ark of God.” So David went and brought the ark of God up from the house of Obed-edom to the city of David with joy.

What motivated David to quickly remove the ark out of the house of Obed-edom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now it was reported to King David, saying, “The Lord has blessed the
> house of Obed-edom and all that belongs to him, on account of the ark
> of God.” So David went and brought the ark of God up ***from the house of
> Obed-edom to the city of David with joy***. 2 Sam 6:12 NASB

> And it was told king David, saying, The Lord hath blessed the house of
> Obededom, and all that pertaineth unto him, because of the ark of God.
> So David went and brought up the ark of God ***from the house of Obededom
> into the city of David with gladness***. 2 Sam 6:12 KJV

It does not say quickly but that he went and moved it with joy/gladness, David was happy before that the priesthood was struck of a curse and not a blessing.

1 Ch 15:13 “For because you did not do it the first time, the LORD our God broke out against us, because we did not consult Him about the proper order.”

Answer (score 2):

It was neither with haste nor jealously that David decided to bring the Ark to Jerusalem.  Note the comments of Ellicott in 2 Sam 6:12 -

> (12) Went and brought up.—The immediate reason for David’s action was
> the knowledge of the blessings which had come to Obed-edom through the
> presence of the ark, in contrast to the punishment of Uzzah; yet this
> implies neither jealousy nor a wish to deprive his subject of a
> blessing. It had been his original purpose to carry the ark to
> Jerusalem, and he had only desisted in a fit of vexation and then of
> fear. He now saw that such fear was groundless, and went on to the
> completion of his unfinished action. The word “with gladness” means
> with festal shouts and rejoicings.

Thus, David saw that the anger of the LORD was only temporary and solely against Uzzah.  He also wanted the blessings that were falling on the house of Obed-edom to fall on the nation as a whole and thus desired to place the Ark in a central location to achieve this.

Thus, David's motives were entirely honorable.  Benson reaches an identical conclusion:

> 2 Samuel 6:12. That God had blessed the house of Obed-edom because of
> the ark — They could not tell to what to impute the extraordinary
> prosperity and happiness that attended him, but to his willing
> reception and care of the ark. And it is certain it was, under God,
> owing to this. David went and brought up the ark to the city of David
> — Hoping God would bless him and his city, as he had done Obed-edom
> and his house.

The Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary add further details -

> 12. it was told king David, saying, The Lord hath blessed the house of Obed-edom, and all that pertaineth unto him, because of the ark of
>     God—The lapse of three months not only restored the agitated mind of
>     the monarch to a tranquil and settled tone, but led him to a discovery
>     of his former error. Having learned that the ark was kept in its
>     temporary resting-place not only without inconvenience or danger, but
>     with great advantage, he resolved forthwith to remove it to the
>     capital, with the observance of all due form and solemnity (1Ch
>     15:1-13). It was transported now on the shoulders of the priests, who
>     had been carefully prepared for the work, and the procession was
>     distinguished by extraordinary solemnities and demonstrations of joy.